Why does the UI become choppy and unresponsive under moderate load?
This happens under any moderate load, but I can reliably reproduce the issue by running npm ci, which installs packages in a user sandbox. Running any other non-sudo build is sufficient. The build involves downloading many individual files and assembling source code.
I understand that a computer has many processes — programs in execution — that compete for its resources. The UI is undoubtedly one or more such processes, and as such, it must sometimes wait in line until the operating system decides it is time to do UI stuff.
However, it seems that this UI stall happens even if none of these resources is even remotely expended:

Are there some resources other than memory, disk write bandwidth, network bandwidth, and CPU time, that could possibly be the bottleneck in case of UI? GPU time comes to mind, but there are two reasons why this should not be a bottleneck:

None of the build processes do anything with GPU.
UI rendering is a very basic 2D rectangle wrangling, unlikely to make the GPU break out a sweat.

Any hint that would help me identify this annoyance and guide me to a solution is warmly appreciated. Buying new hardware is OK, I just have no idea which.
